# What layer stood behind JAXP plugging capabilities?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxp

So lets asume that we want to make XSLT transformation and we want to use.

```
 TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); (1)
```

So newInstance() create object from abstract class which is impossible in Java. SO what happends behind? How Java changes the implementation. I know that you can use directlly

```
TransformerFactory transFact = new org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

but here we have contcrete instance of non-abstract class. Or we can use

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",    
        "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

or even the default implementation (1) from `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax;`

> Designed to be flexible, JAXP allows you to use any XML-compliant
>   parser from within your application. It does this with what is called
>   a pluggability layer, which lets you plug in an implementation of the
>   SAX or DOM API. The pluggability layer also allows you to plug in an
>   XSL processor, letting you control how your XML data is displayed.

How this layer works? Can I write such in my application? To create instace of abstract class?

Comment: They never create an instance of an abstract class, only an instance of a class that *extends* an abstract class. All this configuration layer around it is to specify what class needs to be instantiated when an instance of an abstract class is requested.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc of `TransformerFactory.newInstance()` describes in detail how the concrete implementation of `TransformerFactory` is determined:

> This method uses the following ordered lookup procedure to determine
>   the TransformerFactory implementation class to load:
>
> - Use the javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory system property.
> - Use the properties file "lib/jaxp.properties" in the JRE directory. This configuration file is in standard java.util.Properties
>     format and contains the fully qualified name of the implementation
>     class with the key being the system property defined above. The
>     jaxp.properties file is read only once by the JAXP implementation and
>     it's values are then cached for future use. If the file does not exist
>     when the first attempt is made to read from it, no further attempts
>     are made to check for its existence. It is not possible to change the
>     value of any property in jaxp.properties after it has been read for
>     the first time.
> - Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification), if available, to determine the classname. The Services API will look for
>     a classname in the file
>     META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory in jars
>     available to the runtime.
> - Platform default TransformerFactory instance.

If you want to integrate a similar factory mechanism in your application I would recommend to take a look at the services API.

Comment: OK I saw the flow before but how JDK do it? It uses reflection and then run-time based on these criteria to plug the right implementation?

Comment: Xelian: the lookup results in a class name, and the rest is `Class.forName().newInstance()`

Answer (score 0):

`newInstance()` is a factory method that creates instance of concrete class that is a subclass of `TransformerFactory`.

I have not investigated the source code but can assume that at the end of the day it uses `Class.forName()` to get class and then `Class.newInstance()` to get instance. As you mentioned yourself there is the factory method uses system property `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` to get the fully qualified class name of concrete implementation of the `TransformerFactory`.